# Бот отвечает дважды, почему?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Всем привет! Хочу написать бота, который будет что-то раздавать раз в сутки.
Моя проблема в том, что бот дважды принимает команду `/start`

Но мне нужно, чтобы он принимал её только раз в сутки.

Сам код:

```py
import telebot
import time


bot = telebot.TeleBot("")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hello(message):
    while True:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!")
        time.sleep(60)


bot.polling()
```

```
while True
```

Написал для теста, планируется что там будет `if`

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Почему Вы в обработчике запускаете бесконечный цикл? Зачем Вы вообще привели этот код, если не планируете его использовать в таком виде? В общем, как я понял, Вам нужно запоминать, вводилась ли команда `start/` в течение дня. Так подключите БД (например, `SQLite`) и запоминайте это, связывая с `id` пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я просто новичок, недавно начал, ещё не работал с БД, не могли бы привести пример, как это будет выглядеть?

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['video'])
def video_command(message):
    print(message)
    global lections
    video_today = day_lections(1) #Массив, сегодняшнии лекции
    if video_today == []:
        out_text = "К счастью сегодня лекций нет"
    else:
        out_text = "*Лекции в ближайшие 24 часа*"
        for i in video_today:
            out_text +="\n" + i["name"] + " " + str(i["datetime"]) + " в " + "["+ i["platform"] +"](" + i["link"] + ")"
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        out_text,
        parse_mode="Markdown"
  )
```

Это пример моего кода для бота с if. И он отправляет 1 сообщение. Убедится в этом вы можете, например написав вместо `while True:` вот это `if True:`. Повторная отправка сообщения связана с тем, что функция `hello(msg)` вызывается в том случае если боту пришло `'start'`, и он на это не ответил. Соответственно на 1-ом проходе цикла бот отправляет ваше сообщение, идёт на 2-ой, но так как. сервер телеграмма еще не успел обработать 1-ое сообщение он отправляет еще одно.

Answer (score 0):

Совсем не нужно вечный цикл)

```
import telebot
import time


bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hello(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!")
    # time.sleep(60) Это 60 секунд, что бы получить сутки (24 часа) нужно домножить на 60, выйдет 3600, это час и на 24 - 86400, поэтому пишем - 
    time.sleep(86400)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Но лучше всего не делать `time.sleep()` в основном цикле потому что это будет глушить бота и он не будет отвечать. Что бы не допустить такого используем `threading` -

```
import telebot
import time
import threading


bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hello(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!")
    time.sleep(86400)

threading.Thread(target = hello, args = (1,), daemon = True).start()

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Таким образом у нас и 24 часа будут считаться и бот будет работать дальше, отвечать на другие команды

Comment: А не может ли `telebot` сам обрабатывать запросы в отдельном потоке? Или мб уже уже так делает? Например, у python-telegram-bot для обработки запросов в отдельном потоке нужно к ним добавлять декоратор `run_async`, а для свежих версий в `Handle` указывать параметр `run_async=True`. Проверить это просто -- в функции засуньте `print(threading.current_thread())` и смотрите что выводится в консоли, если каждый раз поток разный, то многопоточная обработка. Еще можно `sleep` оставить и проверить, что бот принимает запросы и отвечает

Comment: Кст, а код с `Thread(target = hello` работает? Меня смущает, что вы его запускаете и в аргументы передаете `1`, а это ведь будет передано в `message`, у которого не будет атрибута `chat`, ведь это заполняет бот при получении сообщения

Answer (score -2):

Во-первых, тебе нужен токен, + надо добавить строку с кое-чем (времени объяснять нет) перед `bot.polling()`. Вот классный видеоурок который все объясняет.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8fhrtvedHA

Попробуй убрать `while True`. Так как сообщение аргумент постоянно выполняться. Сообщение отправляется дважды.